# Creating dummy customer in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have very severe issue. In customer module, I can see many dummy entries. on front end we don't have any provision to create customer.

How these customers are created?

Which patch should I apply to prevent it.?

[image]

Comment: how can customer can create account in your website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue in one of my website.

I don't know which method they are using to create spam account in my website but to stop this type of spamming account we use captcha on customer registration form.

To enable captcha in magento you can use following step

Go to System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA

and enable captcha for form as below, this setting will enable captcha for selected forms.

[image]

Comment: Thnks ,..I have done it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue on my website.

Some users were created with **.ru email** accounts.

To stop this type of spamming account, enable captcha on customer registration form.

```
System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA
```

Enable captcha for form as below, Then it will enable captcha for selected forms.

[image]

Comment: Thnks for your time.. I have done it.

Comment: @mayur, you are welcome, you also faced .ru accounts right?

Comment: me too i was facing same problem few days ago

Comment: yes, when i found this on admin, i modified .htaccess with ips deny, But, that emails are in from 100s of ips, Then i enabled the captcha, now its fine

Comment: I have already accepted. @TejabhagavanKollepara